# Is it possible to raise "onclientclick" event automatically with program

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to raise "onclientclick" event automatically with program.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:show();return false;" Text="here"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Here i need to call `show()` function in some areas of program. I know to call using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. But i dont want to use that. Is there any possibility?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
  <asp:linkbutton id="LinkButton1"
           text="Open Web site"
           onclientclick="Show()"
           onclick="LinkButton1_Click"
           runat="Server" />
```

and javasript like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function Show()
          {
            alert('messagebox');
          }    

        </script>
```

if you want to return some thing from your javascript, you can try like this.

```
OnClientClick="JavaScript: return ReturnSomething();"
```

javascript with return values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ReturnSomething()
    { 
      if(notvalid)
      { 
         return false; // returning false will cancel postback
       }
      else
         return true; 
    }

    </script>
```

Edited :  you can add like this. in your code file.

```
lnkbutton.Attributes.Add("onclientclick", "javascript:return Show();");
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.....I think you didin't understood my question....What i am asking is "How can i trigger OnClientClick event automatically".

Comment: automatically means what  ??  any event will call after it has been invoked

Comment: firing the event using program

Comment: what program ?? where ? on which event you need this ?? are you refering in cs code file ??